# Get Excel cell properties that have been copied to the clipboard

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to copy the values from multiple cells into one cell. If I only wanted to have the values of the cells combined, I would use something like

```
Dim str as string = My.Computer.ClipBoard.GetText
oxlapp.ActiveCell.Value = str
```

**However**

In this case I need to include html tagging, to create a table and I also want to include formatting like bold, italic and underlined. Therefore, instead of just the text from the clipboard, I need to know some cell properties.

I know that they should be there, because you can copy/paste entire cells of course.

So far I tried getting the Excel cells by using

```
My.Computer.Clipboard.GetData(XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatTable)
```

and

```
My.Computer.Clipboard.GetData(XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatCSV)
```

but while debugging I noticed that both of them returned `Nothing`.

**Does someone know how I can get all cell properties from the clipboard?**

To make it more clear, I want this

[image]

To turn into this:

[image]

**If there is any other way than using the clipboard, I would be happy to try.**

Comment: You're copying cells, and trying to paste the values, format, etc of those copied cells? Is this all within Excel? Why are you trying to get the info from the clipboard?

Comment: Hi Bruce. I'm trying to get the values and formats of cells that have been copied and combine all the values and put them into one cell, where I want to convert the format of the cells into html tagging and use html table tags between the values of the different cells. I want to use the clipboard because I thought it would contain all data that I need.

Comment: I think you're going to run into a lot of issues trying to use the clipboard to parse all the formatting. Even with the just those simply formatted cells you have selected there, the clipboard has an array of 24 XlClipboardFormats (oxlapp.ClipboardFormats) being used together, so that's a lot to sift through. Plus, some of the clipboard data references embedded styles in the worksheet and won't be meaningful out of context without a lot more work. So if you already have a range of cells selected, is there a reason you aren't just getting the cell style straight from the cell ranges?

Comment: I tried using `Selection` but that of course pointed me to the cell I want everything to paste in. In that case I think I need to save the previous selection every time I change the selection with all kind of ways that it can go wrong.

Comment: To clarify a bit more, your end goal is a Html encoded string stored in cell.  You do not expect the see cell as the formatted table, just the Html text. Correct?

Comment: @TnTinMn exactly. I later use the cell content In another system that renders it as html.

Comment: Then just use `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)`.  This will return a string in the [HTML Clipboard Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format).  Read through that link to learn how to extract the Html from the returned string; it is not hard and if you search, you will likely find code to perform the extraction.

Comment: Thanks. That gets me the html code. It does require some editing though, since it for instance uses a style sheet and I can't use that. If there is no cleaner way I will definitely use this!

Comment: @TnTinMn I have just tested - and `TextDataFormat.Html` doesn't work. I have enumerated all available formats after copying a range and found out that one needs to use `Clipboard.GetData("HTML Format")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another format from clipboard - `XML Spreadsheet`. The copied data is contained in special XML with its own structure and attributes. Let's take the following sheet's data:

[image: IMG1]

As you see, every cell has some formatting. The XML for this data is the following:

```
<ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
             xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
             xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
             xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
             xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <ss:Styles>
        <ss:Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
            <ss:Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
            <ss:Borders/>
            <ss:Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="204" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
            <ss:Interior/>
            <ss:NumberFormat/>
            <ss:Protection/>
        </ss:Style>
        <ss:Style ss:ID="s62">
            <ss:Interior ss:Color="#FFFF00" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </ss:Style>
        <ss:Style ss:ID="s63">
            <ss:Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="204" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
        </ss:Style>
        <ss:Style ss:ID="s64">
            <ss:Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="204" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#0000FF"/>
        </ss:Style>
        <ss:Style ss:ID="s65">
            <ss:Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="204" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Italic="1"/>
        </ss:Style>
    </ss:Styles>
    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">A</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s63">
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">1</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">B</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s65">
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">2</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
        </ss:Table>
    </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

As you see, you have all information about formatting in corresponding styles. For instace, value `A` in `A1` cell has style `s62` (`StyleID` attribute) - you can find the appropriate `Style` node with this number in `Styles` node. The structure of rows and columns in this XML is implicit - i.e. you won't see indexes of rows and columns - you need to calculate them yourself. For instance, the second `Cell` node in first `Row` node is *first row, second column*.

The following code generates data in the picture above and retrieves appropriate elements to manipulate.

**A word of caution 1.** If you take a look closely, the `Workbook` node has **two** `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet` namespaces: first is default and second is with prefix `ss`. Just remember - you always need to use `ss` prefix!

**A word of caution 2.** This method has one *drawback* - it doesn't understand hidden rows (manually or by autofilter) and columns! It includes hidden rows/columns, too!

```
Imports <xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
Imports <xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

Sub GetCellsWithFormat()
    '// Create new Excel app
    Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application With {.Visible = True}
    Dim book = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim sheet = DirectCast(book.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    '// Apply some formatting
    With sheet
        .Range("A1").Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow
        .Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A2").Font.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBlue
        .Range("B2").Font.Italic = True
        '// Add some values
        Dim arr = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(String), {2, 2}, {1, 1})
        arr(1, 1) = "A" : arr(1, 2) = "1"
        arr(2, 1) = "B" : arr(2, 2) = "2"
        With .Range("A1:B2")
            .Value = arr
            .Copy() '//Copy cells to clipboard
        End With
        Dim xml As XElement
        Using xml_stream = DirectCast(Clipboard.GetData("XML Spreadsheet"), Stream)
            '// Get rid of last character (new line) to avoid parsing error
            xml_stream.SetLength(xml_stream.Length - 1)
            xml = XElement.Load(xml_stream)
        End Using
        '// Get any element you need
        Dim styles = xml.<ss:Styles>(0)
        Dim table = xml.<ss:Worksheet>.<ss:Table>(0)
        Dim rows = table.<ss:Row>
        '// Do something with this data
    End With
End Sub
```

#### UPDATE

In fact, *you don't need to use clipboard* to get this XML - you just need to use `xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet` value of `Value` property:

```
With sheet
    '// Same code...
    With .Range("A1:B2")
        .Value = arr
        '.Copy() '//No need to copy!
    End With
    Dim xml_string = CStr(.Range("A1:B2").Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet))
    '// Again, exclude last character
    Dim xml = XElement.Parse(xml_string.Substring(0, xml_string.Length - 1))
    '// Get any element you need
    Dim styles = xml.<ss:Styles>(0)
    Dim table = xml.<ss:Worksheet>.<ss:Table>(0)
    Dim rows = table.<ss:Row>
    '// Do something with this data
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This will work very well. I want to use the clipboard, because that is the most native way of storing selected data when you already selected a new cell and therefore the easiest to explain to end users. Anyway, I'm very happy with your suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexdeJong I'm sorry - I forgot to include namespaces! Now fixed! 

Comment: @AlexdeJong Also, if you need HTML, you need to use `Dim html = CStr(Clipboard.GetData("HTML Format"))`. You can see all available formats and play with them with the following code: `Dim formats As String() = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats()`. This will return string array.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I think that I stick with this however, because it gives me the opportunity to write the html myself. This html string is the input for external html rendering software, which can only do the most basic stuff. No styling, no colspan, just simple tags.

Comment: @AlexdeJong Glad that helped!  By the way, I was figuring out all of this recently. The discovery of including hidden rows/columns was accident and surprising! I have updated answer - hidden columns are included too.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to allow data copied from Excel into a custom windows app that I wrote, I use GetText() instead of GetData().

Dim ClipboardText As String = Nothing

```
   ClipboardText = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
```

If it is multiple cells that are copied to the Clipboard from Excel, they could be seperated by vbTab and vbCrLf depending on the selection.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but it doesn't give me the formatting. I also want to know if values are bold, italic or underlined.